# Conditionally replace columns with NA

Tags: r, dplyr

here is an example of my data:

```
m <- data.frame(swim = c(0,1,0,0), time1 = c(1,2,3,4), time2 = c(2,3,4,5))
```

I want to replace all numbers in columns time1 and time2 with `NA` after the row where there is a `1` in `m$swim`.  It should look like this:

```
n <- data.frame(swim = c(0,1,0,0), time1 = c(1,2,NA,NA), time2 = c(2,3,NA,NA))

Thank you!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
m %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('time'), 
           ~replace(., row_number() > match(1, swim), NA)))
```

A base R option however, would be more efficient.

```
cols <- grep('time', names(m))
inds <- match(1, m$swim)
m[(inds + 1):nrow(m), cols] <- NA
m
#  swim time1 time2
#1    0     1     2
#2    1     2     3
#3    0    NA    NA
#4    0    NA    NA
```

Comment: dplyr solution works great. note: you need dplyr version 1.0.0 or later to use the new across() function

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` solution would be:

```
#Data
m <- data.frame(swim = c(0,1,0,0), time1 = c(1,2,3,4), time2 = c(2,3,4,5))
#Detect position
index <- min(which(m$swim==1)) 
#Replace
m[(index+1):dim(m)[1],-1] <- NA
```

Output:

```
  swim time1 time2
1    0     1     2
2    1     2     3
3    0    NA    NA
4    0    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table, the result would be as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(m)

#Start after the row with the 1
stop.here <- which(m$swim == 1)+1

these_rows <- seq(stop.here,length(m$swim),1)

m <- m[these_rows,time1:=NA]
m <- m[these_rows,time2:=NA]
```